# How to call multiple Servlets from the same onclick tag?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have to call two Servlets when we click on same button.

```
<tr style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="window.location.href='<%=(String)request.getAttribute("base_url")%>job/create/?jobid=<%= jobData[d].job_id %>';">
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can call multiple servlets on the same event as once the form is posted to first sevelts the control flow is not in your hands... what you can do is use any of AJAX frameworks.. call first servlets get the response and then call second servlet get the reponse and then you can do any logic on both the responses...

Answer (score 0):

You can call one servlet and from there process the parameter you want to. From this servlet after the processing you can call another servlet and process the parameters there.